# How can I custom order the product display?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic, shortcode

I want to put this:

```
[products ids="17,32,12,1,57"]
```

And I want them to display in EXACTLY this order.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `woocommerce_shortcode_products_query` filter to change `orderby` argument. it will set `orderby` as `post__in` in `[products]` shortcode query. I have tested and it is working fine for me. you can take reference from below code and adjust code as per your need. Let me know if this works for you!

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_query', 'woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby_post_in' );
function woocommerce_shortcode_products_orderby_post_in( $args ) {
    if( isset( $args['orderby'] ) ) {
        $args['orderby']  = 'post__in'; 
    }
    return $args;
}
```

Comment: Looks like that worked! thanks very much!

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried to use the 
orderby="menu_order"
parameter in the shortcode? You can set the menu order inside each pruduct.